# Java How to make methods in Interface must-implemented

Tags: java, methods, interface, implementation

I've got a problem. I have an Interface and some methods in it. I need that if these methods aren't implemented you get an error

My Code:

```
public interface someInterface
{
     public default double someDouble(double x)
     {
        return x;
    
     }

}
```

Comment: Then don't make it a default method. Leave it abstract (`double someDouble(double x);` and that's it)

Comment: Thank you, @ernest_k! It was a solution!

Comment: Your interface method must must not contain a body.

Answer (score 0):

By-default if an interface is having plain definition then it's must for a developer to implement it.

For example: If we have following interface

```
public interface someInterface
{
 public double someDouble(double x)
 {
    return x;
 }
}
```

default interface concept was introduced in Java 8 which gives an option to skip implementation.

So we just need to remove default keyword.